# Monitoring Hosting Performance

Tags: performance, wordpress, hosting, onload

I've been building a site, running Wordpress 3.2.1 and noticed
the performance is sluggish in the front and back end. 
I believe the problem is hosting specific.

The problem seems to be the connection loading the actual HTML
which is taking about 5.5 seconds. It appears to finish after
about 500ms, but does not stop loading for 3-4 more seconds.

Here is the development URL:
http://d1001488.u57.ukisp.com/dev/

Hosting:
Windows NT 
PHP Version 5.2.10

There are a couple of jQuery select boxes that get
replaced and styled onload (in the footer), these take a 
long time to get replaced after the page fully loads.

The hosts are claiming all is running properly. Is there
any thing I can try and tweak or monitor to see what
is going on? Or any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For largely *extrinsic* causes, try [YSlow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh). This will identify a number of things you can work on. It won't tell you anything about the internal behavior of your server, but it may help you narrow down what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I already use YSlow, the site grades A. Only other areas is compression, removing the etags and setting expires headings. Not sure how to do those on a windows server. But also don't think those are the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be a specific plugin. Here's what I would recommend:

1. Try going through each plugin, deactivating it, and see if that makes your site load faster. Do this for each plugin, and if a deactivated plugin doesn't improve performance then just reactivate it and move to the next one.
2. Try temporarily activating the default Twenty Eleven theme. See if the default theme loads faster. If it does, then we can look at your custom theme.

These two things may help narrow down at least *where* the problem is coming from. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CPanel access with your hosting account? If you do, look in the left side toolbar at the bottom you should see where it says server status (click to view) you will see various details about your server performance.

Comment: The hosting has some bespoke control panel, no performance options / reporting.

Comment: Have you checked your FTP for performance logs? Maybe you can find some info in the log. It doesn't sound like your host allows installing any CPanel add-on's, so hopefully it's standard.